# How to calculate end a div scroll on chrome?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-chrome

I have a div tag with a height of 100 pixels and overflow-y is set to auto. I have written some jquery code that checks to see if the scroll has reached all the way at the bottom. I am using this for a inifite scroll project I am working on.

This it seems to work fine for Firefox, but not for Chrome. Anybody might have an idea why it's not working for Chrome?

Below is my code.

```
<script>

$( "#scroll" ).scroll(function() {

    var content = $(this).scrollTop() + $(this).innerHeight();

    if (content == $(this)[0].scrollHeight) {

        // $( "span" ).css( "display", "inline" ).fadeOut( "slow" );
        console.log("reach end");

    }
});



</script>


        <style>
        #scroll{

  max-height: 100px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  width: 647px;
  margin: auto;
        }
    </style>


<div id='scroll'>
<p>hello world</p>
<p>hello world</p>
<p>hello world</p>
<p>hello world</p>
<p>hello world</p>
<p>hello world</p>
<p>hello world</p>
<p>hello world</p>
<p>hello world</p>
<p>hello world</p>
<p>hello world</p>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the values Chrome gives for the height, it only ever reaches ([in this example](https://jsfiddle.net/461hmt4q/)) 401.81817626953125 when the value you want is 402, so make sure you round up.

```
var content = Math.ceil($(this).scrollTop() + $(this).innerHeight());
```

Just in case the value is higher, I would also change this line to greater than or equal to

```
if (content >= $(this)[0].scrollHeight) {
```